# Google Places API Invalid request

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I've started looking into Google Places API recently and have enabled the API through my Google Developer Console. I tested the API through the following URL in my browser (please note that I have intentionally changed my key below):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=hotel&location=43.683308,-79.614296&radius10000&key=thisismykey478erjr84

Worked fine, I got back the XML, but when I tried it again I got the following:

```
<PlaceSearchResponse>
    <status>INVALID_REQUEST</status> 
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

Now, as far as I know I'm given a courtesy limit of 1,000 requests/day. I know I did not go over 1000 requests. I figured maybe I'm only allowed a certain number of requests per hour or per minute so I waited.

Next day same problem! And today as well.

Not sure what to do in this case, any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `radius` parameter is missing the `=` separator.  Try `radius=10000`.

Comment: I am a total moron. Thanks for the help!